# ImportError: cannot import name - two modules with the same name

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I can't understand why I'm getting an ImportError. As far as I can tell, there is no circular dependency. Does it have to do with the fact that I have two files named "constants.py"? How would I resolve this?

Below is my directory structure (irrelevant files and folders removed):

```
<top-level directory>
├───spam
│   │   constants.py
│   │   spam.py
│   └───__pycache__
│           constants.cpython-37.pyc
│           spam.cpython-37.pyc
│
├───project_metrics
│   │   main.py
│   ├───data
│   ├───spam_x_ham
│   │   │   constants.py
│   │   │   spam_x_ham.py
│   │   │
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   │           constants.cpython-37.pyc
```

In spam/spam.py:

```
from constants import A, B, C
```

spam/constants.py defines variables A, B, and C.

In project_metrics/spam_x_ham/spam_x_ham.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, <path to top-level directory>)

from constants import X, Y, Z
from spam.spam import foo           # Error raised because of this line
```

project_metrics/spam_x_ham/constants.py defines variables X, Y, and Z.

When I run project_metrics/spam_x_ham/spam_x_ham.py, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<top-level directory>/project_metrics/spam_x_ham/spam_x_ham.py", line 19, in <module>
    from spam.spam import foo
  File "<top-level directory>\spam\spam.py", line 8, in <module>
    from constants import A
ImportError: cannot import name 'A' from 'constants' (<top-level directory>\project_metrics\spam_x_ham\constants.py)
```

I am using python version 3.7.1.

Comment: Is the issue that you want to rename A like `from constants import A as different_name`?

Comment: Your imports are all absolute, their root is one of the directories listed in "sys.path" which automatically also contains the location of the script with which you run the program but not "<top-level directory>\spam". Use relative import like "from .constants import ..."

Comment: @MichaelButscher - I tried using a relative import in spam_x_ham.py ("from .constants import X, Y, Z"), and I get the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '\__main\__.constants'; '\__main\__' is not a package.

Comment: @KentShikama - No, I'm not trying to rename anything.

Comment: @Julian You normally can't do relative imports in the main script (called to start the program) but you can use them in "spam.py".

Comment: @MichaelButscher I tried removing the relative import in spam_x_ham.py and included in spam.py, but I still get the same ImportError as I originally did.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Well, I'm not sure exactly what I did, but after fussing with it some more, making edits then undoing them, the fix to spam.py to call "from .constants import A, B, C" fixed the problem and I can run spam_x_ham.py without issue. However, now when I try to run spam.py alone as its own script, I get an error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.constants'; '__main__' is not a package".

Comment: @Julian If you call `sys.path.insert(...)` in all of your scripts you could also import absolutely from toplevel like `from spam.constants import A, B, C`

Comment: @MichaelButscher I tried adding ``sys.path.insert(0, <path to top-level directory>)`` to both spam.py and spam.constants.py, changing spam.py to say ``from spam.constants import A, B, C``, but now I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module names 'mtf.costants'; 'mtf' is not a package."

Comment: "mtf" is not shown in your directory tree. Or is it an external library?

Comment: Oops, typo - "mtf" should be "spam". So the error says "ModuleNotFoundError: No modules named 'spam.constants'; 'spam' is not a package."